# Sitecore ECM on CD is unable to find a campaign by ID (different core databases)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I am getting the following exception when clicking on an ECM email link that points to content delivery server,

```
Campaign with ID {} has not been found.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.EmailResponse.HandleEmailLinkClickResponse(String link, Guid campaignId, Guid automationStateId)
```

It all works if I change the URL from CD host to CM host.

Sitecore 7.1 with E-mail Campaign Manager 2.1 rev. 140214
CM and CD are configured to use different **core** databases.

Is there anyway to get ECM working in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to publish two folders with children,

/sitecore/system/Marketing Center/Campaigns
/sitecore/content/Home/Email Campaign Manager/Messages/